# Reading a formatted file in masm

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

I am trying to read a file that has lines like this

201;18,5;2500;35 (4 information, the second one is a float, the others are ints)

And I want to convert these numbers to decimal (to operate with). I wont use the 8086 float capabilities, for example "18,5" , I will multiply 18 by 1000 plus 5 times 100, and the sum them in one number (won't reach 64k).

I know the logics, but I don't know how to do it.

I need to read until I get ";" or "," or "CR" (CRLF marks the lines)

Here's what I have so far

```
atoi    proc near
        mov     ax,0
atoi_2:
        cmp     byte ptr[bx], 0
        jz      atoi_1
        mov     cx,10
        mul     cx
        mov     ch,0
        mov     cl,[bx]
        add     ax,cx
        sub     ax,'0'
        inc     bx
        jmp     atoi_2    
atoi_1:
        ret    
atoi    endp


read_char_convert proc near
put_on_string: ;To convert using atoi       
    cmp     FileBuffer, AscSemiColon ; is it ";"?
    je      column_count
    cmp     FileBuffer, AscComma     ; Is it ","?
    je      fechar_string_comma
    cmp     FileBuffer, CR           ; Is it "CR"?
    je      close_string_CR

    ;I CANT DO THIS
    ;add    String, i
    ;mov    String, FileBuffer
    ;inc    i
    mov     si, i
    mov     String[si], FileBuffer ;THIS IS GETTING ME AN ERROR
    inc     i    
close_string_comma:

columnCount:
    call    columnCounter
fechar_string_CR:
    mov     SemiColonCounter, 0 ; going to the next line
read_char_convert endp

columnCounter proc near
    inc     i 
    mov     si, i
    mov     String[si], 0
    inc     SemiColonCounter
    cmp     SemiColonCounter, 1 
    je      chamaConversaoTempo
    cmp     SemiColonCounter, 2
    je      chamaConversaoBateria
    cmp     SemiColonCounter, 3
    je      chamaConversaoDistancia
    cmp     SemiColonCounter, 4
    je      chamaConversaoVelocidade

callTimeConversion:
    call    speedConversion
    jmp     return_columnCounter
callBatteryConversion:
    call    batteryConversion
    jmp     return_columnCounter
callDistanceConversion:
    call    distanceConversion
    jmp     return_columnCounter
callSpeedConversion:
    call    speedConversion
    ;jmp    return_columnCounter

retourn_columnCounter:
    ret
columnCounter endp

timeConversion proc near    
    lea     bx, String
    call    atoi
    mov     T_PARCIAL1, ax
    cmp     nbr_lines, 1
    jne     returnTime
    mov     bx, T_INICIAL
    mov     T_PARCIAL1, bx
returnTime:
    ret
timeConversion endp

batteryConversion proc near

    lea     bx, String
    call    atoi
    ;cmp    b_int, 1 ; flag -> 1 int part, 0, decimal part
    jne     mult_100
    mov     ax, THOUSAND ;constant
    mul     ax
    mov     B_PARCIAL1, ax
    jmp     jump_100
mult_100:
    mov     ax, HUNDRED
    mul     ax
    add     B_PARCIAL1, ax
jump_100:       
    cmp     nbr_lines, 1
    jne     returnBattery
    mov     bx, B_INICIAL
    mov     B_PARCIAL1, bx    
returnBattery:
    ret
batteryConversion endp

distanceConversion proc near    
    lea     bx, String
    call    atoi
    mov     D_PARCIAL1, ax
    cmp     nbr_lines, 1
    jne     returnDistance
    mov     bx, D_INICIAL
    mov     D_PARCIAL1, bx
returnDistance:
    ret
distanceConversion endp

speedConversion proc near

    lea     bx, String
    call    atoi
    mov     V_PARCIAL1, ax
    cmp     nbr_lines, 1
    jne     returnSpeed
    mov     bx, V_INICIAL
    mov     V_PARCIAL1, bx
returnSpeed:
    ret
speedConversion endp
```

Can you guys help me out? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> mov     String[si], FileBuffer ;THIS IS GETTING ME AN ERROR
> ```

This is MASM!

When MASM *sees* the second operand (`FileBuffer`) it will treat it as a memory operand.
But the first operand (`String[si]`) is a memory operand too.

You can't have 2 memory operands like this in the same instruction, hence the error message.

I didn't follow the rest of the code (a bit long and without the desperately needed comments) but next 2 solutions might do the job for you.

- Turn the second operand into an immediate:

  ```
  mov     String[si], offset FileBuffer
  ```
- Read and write in separate steps:

  ```
  mov      al, FileBuffer
  mov      String[si], al
  ```

Comment: Hey, thanks, I did that, could you help me in finding a way to read those values separately?

Comment: This is how my program is right now

https://pastebin.com/7Gv2VpJ7

And an input file example

https://pastebin.com/recaLkTF